# How to display a "loading..." dialog?

Tags: android

I would just like to display something like a dialog (but dialogs are modal only, right?)

when my activity is loading data in onCreate()

and to dismiss this "dialog" when complete.

Just to inform the user that data is loading.

How can I do this easily?

*I do not want the user to be able to interact with the UI during this period.. just for him to sit and wait until data is loaded.*

Comment: I implemented using Progress Dialog and AsyncTask... works well now, I was just doing some things wrong the first time I tried it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for me was to use ProgressDialog and an AsyncTask

https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/asynctasks-with-progressdialogs

Answer (score 2):

See [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog).

Here some element:

```
// keep a reference on the dialog (class member)
ProgressDialog mWaitingDialog;

// when you start loading the data
mWaitingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);

// when data have been loaded
mWaitingDialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
```